# XSLT Transformation : Looping through XML to get Node and Values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an input XML and I want to transform it to some other XML using XSLT.

Input XML :

```
  <XML>
        <Fields>
                    <F1> Val1 </F1>
                    <F2> Val2 </F2>
                    <F1> Val3 </F1>
                    <F4> Val4 </F4>
        </Fields>
        </XML>
```

Output XML :

```
<SomeThing>

    <SomeThing>
                <Field id = "F1"> <val> Val1 </val> </Field>
                <Field id = "F2"> <val> Val2 </val> </Field>
                <Field id = "F3"> <val> Val3 </val> </Field>
                <Field id = "F4"> <val> Val4 </val> </Field>
  </SomeThing>
    </SomeThing>
```

My XSLT : (I know its wrong :( )

```
 <xsl:for-each select="XML/Fields">
                    <field>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            <value> 
                                <xsl:value-of select="current()"/> 
                            </value>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </field>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

XSLT is tough.

Comment: got it, please check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer that is more extensible (as it uses templates), doesn't make use of `<xsl:for-each>`, and doesn't require `<xsl:attribute>`.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <SomeThings>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </SomeThings>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Fields">
    <SomeThing>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </SomeThing>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Fields/*">
    <Field id="{name()}">
      <val>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </val>
    </Field>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the provided XML:**

```
<XML>
  <Fields>
    <F1> Val1 </F1>
    <F2> Val2 </F2>
    <F1> Val3 </F1>
    <F4> Val4 </F4>
  </Fields>
</XML>
```

**...the wanted output is produced:**

```
<SomeThings>
  <SomeThing>
    <Field id="F1">
      <val> Val1 </val>
    </Field>
    <Field id="F2">
      <val> Val2 </val>
    </Field>
    <Field id="F1">
      <val> Val3 </val>
    </Field>
    <Field id="F4">
      <val> Val4 </val>
    </Field>
  </SomeThing>
</SomeThings>
```